# Wordpress Shortcode not working in post editor

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I created shortcode in function.php in wordpress child theme.

here is code I added.

```
add_shortcode('mn','mn_func');
function mn_func($atts){
echo "<p> Testing </p>";
}
```

I added *[mn]* in wordpress post editor but post is showing [mn], not Testing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` a value, not echo it. As the docs for [add_shortcode()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) state (emphasis mine):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce
>   output of any kind. **Shortcode functions should return the text that is
>   to be used to replace the shortcode**. Producing the output directly
>   will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter
>   functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side
>   effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they
>   are called from.

Try:

```
add_shortcode('mn','mn_func');
function mn_func($atts){
    return "<p> Testing </p>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing add_shortcode after the function like this:

```
function mn_func($atts){
     echo "<p> Testing </p>";
}
add_shortcode('mn','mn_func');
```